# Should I keep symfony.lock in my version control?

Tags: symfony-flex

I'm starting to use Symfony Flex to bootstrap my project and I realized that running `composer install` for the first time generates a file named `symfony.lock` for which I could find no documentation.

What does this file do? Should I keep it in my version control and deploy it or should I .gitignore it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, officially you must add it to the version control:

> Flex keeps tracks of the recipes it installed in the `symfony.lock` file, which must be committed to your code repository.
>   https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex#how-does-flex-work

Otherwise on staging or production stages it will be generated again by Flex, auto-configuring all installed packages with [recipes](https://github.com/symfony/recipes) and triggering bugs like this https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/192

Comment: We have our symfony.lock file in our version controler.  However, composer install is actually updating symfony.lock file during every build.  So, I am struggling to understand what benefit we get by keeping symfony.lock in version control.  It is not being honored.